# What context should I give to AlertDialog.Builder?

Tags: kotlin, android-alertdialog

I have a problem with AlertDialog.Builder, I am trying to find the right context to give to                 `builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)` but I keep having this error message  `Type mismatch. Required: Context Found: ProfilFragment`

import : androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog

I really don't know at this point what context to use instead.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access context from a fragment by using `requireContext()`. So pass `requireContext()` instead of `this` in the `AlertDialog.Builder`

Comment: Thank you it worked!